# Filtering a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a JSON like below

```
{
    "status": {
        "On Hold": true,
        "Completed": true,
        "Work In Progress": false,
        "Closed": false,
        "Initiation": false
    },
    "application": {
        "Athena":false,
        "EWindow":false,
        "EWS":true,
        "FACT":false,
        "FTP":false,
        "Hardware":false,
        "Harmony":true,
        "Hermes":false
    }
}
```

I want to filter this json to contain item whose value is true alone like below

```
{"status":"On Hold,Completed","application":"EWS,Harmony"}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Kindly specify you need to filter from javascript or java, also let us know json you retrieve from web service or NoSQL DB like couchDB , MangoDB etc?

Comment: @karaxuna answer is quiet enough!

Comment: Why is this tagged with angularjs? Did you want AngularJS filter on this or ...?

Comment: Actually I am using AngularJS for getting this JSON 'code'<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected.application[application]" ng-change="changeFilter()">{{application}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {"status":{"On Hold":true,"Completed":true,"Work In Progress":false,"Closed":false,"Initiation":false},"application":{"Athena":false,"EWindow":false,"EWS":true,"FACT":false,"FTP":false,"Hardware":false,"Harmony":true,"Hermes":false}}

var newData = {};
for(var prop in data){
     var subData = data[prop];
     var xs = [];
     for(var subProp in subData){
         if(subData[subProp] === true)
              xs.push(subProp);
     }
     newData[prop] = xs.join(',');
}
```